# Jenkins CI - Android Emulator Fails To Start

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator

I've got a Mac Mini server with Jenkins CI 2.7.4 running and have a job set up to build an Android project of mine.  The job also runs an emulator via the Android Emulator Plugin in order to run some Espresso tests.  However, I'm running in to an issue where the emulator never actually starts.  I have the "Show emulator window" option checked.

Here's the output:

```
[android] Using Android SDK: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk
[android] Adding 128M SD card to AVD 'hudson_en-US_120_WXGA720_android-23_x86'...
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5832 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -snapshot-list -no-window -avd hudson_en-US_120_WXGA720_android-23_x86
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
[android] Starting Android emulator and creating initial snapshot
[android] Erasing existing emulator data...
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5730,5731 -report-console tcp:5852,max=60 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_120_WXGA720_android-23_x86 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
2016-09-27 14:31:02.344 emulator64-x86[981:7440] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
PasteBoard: Error creating pasteboard: com.apple.pasteboard.clipboard [-4960]
2016-09-27 14:31:02.344 emulator64-x86[981:7440] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
PasteBoard: Error creating pasteboard: com.apple.pasteboard.find [-4960]
no screens available, assuming 24-bit color
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
QPaintDevice::metrics: Device has no metric information
QPaintDevice::metrics: Device has no metric information
QPaintDevice::metrics: Device has no metric information
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetDefaultUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetDefaultUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetDefaultUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetDefaultUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetDefaultUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetDefaultUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetDefaultUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextGetDefaultUserSpaceToDeviceSpaceTransform: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 27 14:31:02  emulator64-x86[981] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Cannot create window: no screens available
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

I get a timeout error if I uncheck "Show emulator window":

```
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5752 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'running'
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5752 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'running'
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5752 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'running'
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5752 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'running'
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5752 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'running'
[android] Timed-out after waiting 360 seconds for emulator
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run the emulator headless, i.e. not on a logged-in UI session? Does it work without "Show emulator window"?

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing timeouts. I had a similar situation and it did not get solved till I did that.

```
com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences.setTimeOut(600000)
android {
}
```

And add the environment property ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=5

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me.  I tried copying the command and running it in a terminal window and still no luck.  The Android Emulator loading window pops up, but it eventually times out.  However, if I remove "-report-console tcp:5855,max=60" from the command then I can get it to run in the terminal.  Is there a way to override the overall command and parameters in the Android Emulator Plugin?

Comment: `-report-console` isn't useful from a terminal, but it does work from within the plugin (otherwise you wouldn't get as far as "Emulator reported that the startup process is 'running'"). 

You can add additional parameters (under "Advanced"), but you can remove existing ones from the command line used by the plugin.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr, I was able to get it in a working state by simply uninstalling and reinstalling Jenkins CI.  It still shows the `_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer` errors but as long as I don't check the "Show emulator window" option then it will successfully build and run my Espresso jobs.